# Populate Crystal Report with dataset Images

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, dataset, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to Populate Crystal Report with a dataset and trying to load an image. I have the image in a bytes array. Im about to load my string data just fine. I have a dataset with a datatable and some columns.
Here is my code, But im having problems with this line:

```
t.Columns.Add("Item", Type.GetType(System.Byte()))
```

specifically `System.Byte()`

Here is my full code, does anyone know what i should replace that line with?

```
Private Function GetGmap(ByVal objGEOCode As String)
    Dim gmap As New CtpGglMap.Impl.StaticGMap
    Dim temp As New GMarker
    Dim temp2 As New GMarker
    Dim ArrTemp()
    ArrTemp = Split(objGEOCode, ",")
    gmap.Center = New GeoPointImpl(ArrTemp(0), ArrTemp(1))
    gmap.Zoom = 14


    gmap.Height = 159
    gmap.Width = 137
    gmap.Sensor = False
    '  GetDrivingDirectionFromGoogle("fishkill ,ny", "41.5442847, -73.8732391")

    temp.Point = New GeoPointImpl(ArrTemp(0), ArrTemp(1))
    temp.SetMap(gmap)

    'CREATE A BITMAP FROM THE MEMORY STREAM
    Return New System.Drawing.Bitmap(gmap.Fetch)



    Return True
End Function
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ds As New DataSet1
    Dim t As DataTable = ds.Tables.Add("Items")
    t.Columns.Add("id", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    t.Columns.Add("Item", Type.GetType(System.Byte()))

    Dim r As DataRow

    r = t.NewRow()
    r("id") = "Test"
    r("Item") = GetGmap("41.5442847, -73.8732391")
    t.Rows.Add(r)


    Dim objRpt As New CrystalReport1
    objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(1))
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

    CrystalReportViewer1.PrintReport()

End Sub
```